# Suppose that $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $x_{n+1} = (x_n)^2$. Show that $\left\lbrace x_n\right\rbrace$ converges and find lim $x_n $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $x_{n+1} = (x_n)^2$. Show that $\left\lbrace x_n\right\rbrace$ converges and find lim $x_n $.

The hint that the problem gives is "You cannot divide by zero". I want to base the proof on this hint but don't know how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: start by writing down $x_2, x_3, x_4$ to get a feel for what might be the limit of the sequence.

Comment: Hi, but how does the hint fit into this? I want to know how to use that hint. Thank you

Comment: "*I want to base the proof on this hint*"   I don't think its a very good hint personally, you should feel free to ignore it.  I think they're trying to allude to looking at $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$, using induction to note that the sequence is constantly decreasing and constantly greater than zero for any finite index which proves convergence.

Comment: I find it far cleaner to just recognize what the closed form expression is and approach that way.

Comment: @JMoravitz. As you wrote, sometimes, there are hints which are not (and from far away). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$x_1=\frac{1}{2},\\x_2=x_1^2=\frac{1}{4},\\x_3=x_2^2=\frac{1}{16}$$ and so on. This is a monotonically decreasing sequence, and also it converges. Why?

> Think if the sequence $\{x_n\}$ can attain a value less than $0$ or not as the sequence is decreasing. Then apply the **Monotone Convergence Theorem** to know that the sequence converges.

Now, as the sequence converges, thus limit exists (say $L$). Thus, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=L$$

Can you now apply the inductive method and find the limit now?

> $$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=x_n^2\\\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n+1}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n^2\\L&=L^2\\ L&=1,0\end{align}$$Now, $L$ cannot be $1$. Thus, $L=0$.